# Aws commands are not responding

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I was trying to type "aws ec2 describe-instances" it will gives a blink cursor (AWS Command line). No results are showing.I have tried with setting the configurations for the user as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide instance details to get a description. like

`aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-5xxxxbx`